# Prolog programm returns yes instead of value

Tags: prolog

I got the following event: **item(C,X,G,P)**, (*where `C` is a number for the product,`X` it's name,`G` it's price,`P` it's cost*).
When i use the command **`item(n3001,_,_,P)`** directly on the prolog console i get as answer
`G = 1.25 X = 100` but when i write the equation `p3(C)-: item(C,_,_,P).` then i consult the text i get as answer `yes`.
  My question clarified is how come the one time i get the value of `P` which i want and the other time i get whether it's true or false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no return values in Prolog and p3/1 does not constitute a function but a relation. Your definition

```
p3(C) :-
   item(C,_,_,P).
```

reads: If `item(C,_,_,P)` succeeds then `p3(C)` succeeds as well. For the sake of argument, let's assume that your code includes the following fact:

```
item(n3001,100,1.25,1).
```

If you query

```
?- p3(n3001).
```

Prolog unifies `C` in the head of your rule with `n3001` and then tries your goal `item(C,_,_,P)` which succeeds. Hence the rule succeeds and Prolog tells you:

```
   ?- p3(n3001).
yes
```

If you want to know the price corresponding to `n3001` you have to to define a rule where `P` appears in the head of the rule as well, e.g.:

```
p3(C,P) :-
   item(C,_,_,P).
```

If you query that you'll get to see the value of `P` corresponding to `n3001`:

```
   ?- p3(n3001,P).
P = 1
```

If you query item/4 directly `P` appears in the arguments and therefore you get to see a substitution for it that satisfies your query:

```
   ?- item(n3001,_,_,P).
P = 1
```

Comment: It is also possible to see a predicate as a function from terms to boolean values - i.e. true (yes) and false (no). In any case, without an "output" argument, the information is quite limited.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x: Yes, you're absolutely right. But my point is that unless you want to see if a predicate holds for a specific (tuple of) argument(s), you will leave some arguments as variables and have Prolog compute them. So it's usually not very helpful to think about predicates in terms of functions and return values as you would do in other programming paradigms.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x: While right, your mentioned viewpoint obscures the actual point of answers and logic variables, since it is easy to misread as: Nothing new here compared to functions.